# Regarding SPARQL queries on DBPedia SPARQL end point in a loop

Tags: sparql, jena, semantic-web

```java
while((reader=br.readLine())!=null)
{
    System.out.println(reader);
    type="";
    String queryNew="select ?y ?z where {"+reader+" <http://www.w3.org/1999/02/22-rdf-syntax-ns#type> ?z . }";
    Query query=QueryFactory.create(queryNew);

    ARQ.getContext().setTrue(ARQ.useSAX);
    QueryExecution qexec = QueryExecutionFactory.sparqlService("http://dbpedia.org/sparql", query);

    ResultSet results = qexec.execSelect();

    while(results.hasNext())
    {
        QuerySolution soln=results.nextSolution();
        type=type+" "+soln.get("?z");
        System.out.println(soln.get("?y")+" "+soln.get("?z"));
    }

    bw.write(reader+" "+type+"\n"); 
}
```

From a file I am reading actor names and then trying to get all the `rdf:type` links for each actor. While the result prints for the first actor, the rest of the execution gets stuck. The 'reader' is nothing but an actor's name which is the dbpedia resource. Can anyone kindly tell me what might have gone wrong in the code?

Answer (score 4):

You don't show your data, but assuming that the file contains simply the names of actors, as you say, then the query you're actually asking is something like:

```
select ?y ?z where {
    "Matt Damon" rdf:type ?z
}
```

That's never going to return any results, because the *subject* of an RDF triple is always an RDF resource, not a string literal.

You should change your query to:

```
prefix dbpprop: <http://dbpedia.org/property/>
prefix rdf: <http://www.w3.org/1999/02/22-rdf-syntax-ns#>

select ?actor ?type where {
    ?actor dbpprop:name "Matt Damon"@en ;
           rdf:type ?type
}
```

in other words "what are the rdf:types of the resource whose name (in English) is Matt Damon?"

Comment: Hi Ian & Joshua thank you for the answers. The actor names which I am mentioning are actually the resource names from wikipedia. The program took a long time to run but gave partial results in 30 minutes.

Comment: @harrypotter Can you show a bit more of your data, or your input list?  Unless it's particularly big, that seems like a very long time for a fairly simple query.  Also, if you're getting the list of DBpedia IRIs, you might consider using a `values` block to run one big query, rather than one query per actor, where you'll run into rate limiting issues.

Answer (score 1):

As Ian Dickinson pointed out in [his answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/21334755/1281433), you haven't shown us the data, nor what exactly the value of `reader` is, so it's hard to tell exactly what's going wrong.  It does sound like you need to adjust your query to something along the lines of

```
?actor rdfs:label ?label
```

where `?label` is the name of the actor that you're interested in.  If you use string concatenation like you did in

```
String queryNew = "select ?y ?z where {" + reader + " <http://www.w3.org/1999/02/22-rdf-syntax-ns#type> ?z . }";
```

you're opening yourself up to SPARQL injection attacks.  E.g., what would happen if `reader` contains more SPARQL query text?  (Also, because `rdf:type` is so commonly used, SPARQL actually allows you to abbreviate it with `a`, as in `?actor a dbpedia-owl:Person`.)  To avoid this sort of issue, Jena provides a [ParameterizedSparqlString](http://jena.apache.org/documentation/javadoc/arq/com/hp/hpl/jena/query/ParameterizedSparqlString.html) that will take care of proper escaping.  Also note that RDF distinguishes between plain literals, e.g., `"Richard Dreyfuss"` and language tagged strings, e.g., `"Richard Dreyfuss"@en`.  This means that you might want to include language tags in your query.  Finally, note that there might well be more than one thing in DBpedia with a given label.  Heres's code using a parameterized SPARQL string that finds resources with the label `"Richard Dreyfuss"@en`, along with all of their RDF types:

```java
import com.hp.hpl.jena.query.ParameterizedSparqlString;
import com.hp.hpl.jena.query.QueryExecution;
import com.hp.hpl.jena.query.QueryExecutionFactory;
import com.hp.hpl.jena.query.ResultSet;
import com.hp.hpl.jena.query.ResultSetFormatter;
import com.hp.hpl.jena.rdf.model.Literal;
import com.hp.hpl.jena.rdf.model.ResourceFactory;

public class DBpediaQueryExample {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        /*
         * A typed literal: the name Richard Dreyfuss in English.  In SPARQL 
         * this is written as "Richard Dreyfuss"@en.
         */
        final Literal richardDreyfuss = ResourceFactory.createLangLiteral( "Richard Dreyfuss", "en" );

        /*
         * A parameterized SPARQL string for the query.  Using this, along with 
         * the various setZZZ(...) methods can prevent some SPARQL injection 
         * attacks by doing proper escaping.
         */
        final ParameterizedSparqlString queryString = new ParameterizedSparqlString(
                "prefix rdfs: <http://www.w3.org/2000/01/rdf-schema#>\n" +
                "\n" +
                "select ?resource ?type where {\n" +
                "  ?resource a ?type ;\n" +
                "            rdfs:label ?label .\n" +
                "}" );

        /*
         * Fill in "Richard Dreyfuss"@en for the ?label. 
         */
        queryString.setLiteral("label", richardDreyfuss );

        /*
         * Get a query execution that will run against the DBpedia SPARQL
         * endpoint, and will use the parameterized query.
         */
        final QueryExecution exec = QueryExecutionFactory.sparqlService(
                "http://dbpedia.org/sparql",
                queryString.asQuery() );

        /*
         * Execute the query to produce a result set, and format it nicely.
         */
        final ResultSet results = exec.execSelect();
        ResultSetFormatter.out( results );
    }
}
```

```
-------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
| resource                                                              | type                                                                  |
=================================================================================================================================================
| <http://dbpedia.org/resource/Richard_Dreyfuss>                        | <http://www.w3.org/2002/07/owl#Thing>                                 |
| <http://dbpedia.org/resource/Richard_Dreyfuss>                        | <http://dbpedia.org/class/yago/ActorsFromLosAngeles,California>       |
| <http://dbpedia.org/resource/Richard_Dreyfuss>                        | <http://dbpedia.org/class/yago/AmericanFilmActors>                    |
| <http://dbpedia.org/resource/Richard_Dreyfuss>                        | <http://dbpedia.org/class/yago/AmericanTelevisionActors>              |
| <http://dbpedia.org/resource/Richard_Dreyfuss>                        | <http://dbpedia.org/ontology/Agent>                                   |
| <http://dbpedia.org/resource/Richard_Dreyfuss>                        | <http://dbpedia.org/ontology/Person>                                  |
| <http://dbpedia.org/resource/Richard_Dreyfuss>                        | <http://umbel.org/umbel/rc/Actor>                                     |
| <http://dbpedia.org/resource/Richard_Dreyfuss>                        | <http://schema.org/Person>                                            |
| <http://dbpedia.org/resource/Richard_Dreyfuss>                        | <http://xmlns.com/foaf/0.1/Person>                                    |
| <http://dbpedia.org/resource/Richard_Dreyfuss>                        | <http://dbpedia.org/class/yago/AmericanComedians>                     |
| <http://dbpedia.org/resource/Richard_Dreyfuss>                        | <http://dbpedia.org/class/yago/Comedian109940146>                     |
| <http://dbpedia.org/resource/Richard_Dreyfuss>                        | <http://dbpedia.org/class/yago/JewishActors>                          |
| <http://dbpedia.org/resource/Richard_Dreyfuss>                        | <http://dbpedia.org/class/yago/PeopleFromBrooklyn>                    |
| <http://dbpedia.org/resource/Richard_Dreyfuss>                        | <http://dbpedia.org/class/yago/Adult109605289>                        |
| <http://dbpedia.org/resource/Richard_Dreyfuss>                        | <http://dbpedia.org/class/yago/Communicator109610660>                 |
| <http://dbpedia.org/resource/Richard_Dreyfuss>                        | <http://dbpedia.org/class/yago/LivingPeople>                          |
| <http://dbpedia.org/resource/Richard_Dreyfuss>                        | <http://dbpedia.org/class/yago/Object100002684>                       |
| <http://dbpedia.org/resource/Richard_Dreyfuss>                        | <http://dbpedia.org/class/yago/PeopleWithBipolarDisorder>             |
| <http://dbpedia.org/resource/Richard_Dreyfuss>                        | <http://dbpedia.org/class/yago/Person100007846>                       |
| <http://dbpedia.org/resource/Richard_Dreyfuss>                        | <http://dbpedia.org/class/yago/Whole100003553>                        |
| <http://dbpedia.org/resource/Richard_Dreyfuss>                        | <http://dbpedia.org/class/yago/YagoLegalActor>                        |
| <http://dbpedia.org/resource/Richard_Dreyfuss>                        | <http://dbpedia.org/class/yago/Entertainer109616922>                  |
| <http://dbpedia.org/resource/Richard_Dreyfuss>                        | <http://dbpedia.org/class/yago/AlternateHistoryWriters>               |
| <http://dbpedia.org/resource/Richard_Dreyfuss>                        | <http://dbpedia.org/class/yago/Actor109765278>                        |
| <http://dbpedia.org/resource/Richard_Dreyfuss>                        | <http://dbpedia.org/class/yago/AmericanConscientiousObjectors>        |
| <http://dbpedia.org/resource/Richard_Dreyfuss>                        | <http://dbpedia.org/class/yago/AmericanHistoricalNovelists>           |
| <http://dbpedia.org/resource/Richard_Dreyfuss>                        | <http://dbpedia.org/class/yago/ConscientiousObjector109957013>        |
| <http://dbpedia.org/resource/Richard_Dreyfuss>                        | <http://dbpedia.org/class/yago/Dissenter110018021>                    |
| <http://dbpedia.org/resource/Richard_Dreyfuss>                        | <http://dbpedia.org/class/yago/Novelist110363573>                     |
| <http://dbpedia.org/resource/Richard_Dreyfuss>                        | <http://dbpedia.org/class/yago/Performer110415638>                    |
| <http://dbpedia.org/resource/Richard_Dreyfuss>                        | <http://dbpedia.org/class/yago/Writer110794014>                       |
| <http://dbpedia.org/resource/Richard_Dreyfuss>                        | <http://dbpedia.org/class/yago/CausalAgent100007347>                  |
| <http://dbpedia.org/resource/Richard_Dreyfuss>                        | <http://dbpedia.org/class/yago/LivingThing100004258>                  |
| <http://dbpedia.org/resource/Richard_Dreyfuss>                        | <http://dbpedia.org/class/yago/Organism100004475>                     |
| <http://dbpedia.org/resource/Richard_Dreyfuss>                        | <http://dbpedia.org/class/yago/JewishComedians>                       |
| <http://dbpedia.org/resource/Richard_Dreyfuss>                        | <http://dbpedia.org/class/yago/JewishPacifists>                       |
| <http://dbpedia.org/resource/Richard_Dreyfuss>                        | <http://dbpedia.org/class/yago/Pacifist110390199>                     |
| <http://dbpedia.org/resource/Richard_Dreyfuss>                        | <http://dbpedia.org/class/yago/PhysicalEntity100001930>               |
| <http://dbpedia.org/resource/Richard_Dreyfuss>                        | <http://dbpedia.org/class/yago/YagoLegalActorGeo>                     |
| <http://dbpedia.org/resource/Richard_Dreyfuss>                        | <http://dbpedia.org/class/yago/PeopleFromQueens>                      |
| <http://sw.opencyc.org/2008/06/10/concept/en/RichardDreyfuss>         | <http://sw.opencyc.org/2008/06/10/concept/en/ActorInMovies>           |
| <http://sw.opencyc.org/2008/06/10/concept/en/RichardDreyfuss>         | <http://sw.opencyc.org/2008/06/10/concept/en/MaleHuman>               |
| <http://sw.opencyc.org/2008/06/10/concept/Mx4rwOREVpwpEbGdrcN5Y29ycA> | <http://sw.opencyc.org/2008/06/10/concept/Mx4rvVjWoZwpEbGdrcN5Y29ycA> |
| <http://sw.opencyc.org/2008/06/10/concept/Mx4rwOREVpwpEbGdrcN5Y29ycA> | <http://sw.opencyc.org/2008/06/10/concept/Mx4rwMRyTJwpEbGdrcN5Y29ycA> |
-------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
```